Simplicial Generalization of Pythagoras
I recently heard about a claim that

For a triangle in 3-space, its area squared equals the sum of squares of areas of its projections onto three pairwise orthogonal planes.

I currently don't have any proof for that at hand. However, if it were true, in combination with the well-known Pythagoras theorem, where the line segments simply are to be considered as 1D simplices,
it seems that it might become extrapolatable for higher dimensional simplices too:
Then it ought state like this:

For an nD simplex within (n+1)D space, its nD hyper-volume squared equals the sum of the n+1 squares of the nD hyper-volumes of its projections onto the (mutually orthogonal) coordinate hyperplanes.

If that theorem could be proven in general, then Pythagoras would simply become the case n=1 and the heard of claim would just be case n=2.
Thus, any proof would be welcome.
--- rk

FYI: Non-Euclidean counterparts get messy quickly. The hyperbolic Pyth Thm for a right triangle w/legs and hypotenuse $a$, $b$, $c$ is $$\cosh a\cosh b=\cosh c$$ The hyperbolic deGua's Thm for a right-corner tetrahedron w/leg- and hyp-areas $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ is $$\cos(A/2)\cos(B/2)\cos(C/2)-\sin(A/2)\sin(B/2)\sin(C/2)=\cos(D/2)$$
In higher dimensions ... I don't know. In $4D$, leg- and hyp-volumes are encoded in tricky integrals, and it's not at all clear (to me) how they relate, even in the most-symmetric case. See my ancient MathOverflow question.

This is true. It's called de Gua's theorem (from 1783!), and the higher-dimensional generalization is due to Conant and Beyer (from 1974!). The cleanest proof I can think of involves using either exterior algebra or geometric algebra; they are basically equivalent but I'll stick to the exterior algebra since I think it is a little more familiar.
We need the following facts. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real inner product space of dimension $n$ and let $e_1, \dots e_n$ be any orthonormal basis of it.

From $V$ we can form another vector space called the $k$-th exterior power $\Lambda^k(V)$, which consists of sums of symbols of the form $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \dots v_k$ (wedge products or exterior products) subject to the relations that $\wedge$ is associative, antisymmetric ($v \wedge w = - w \wedge v$, or equivalently $v \wedge v = 0$), and bilinear. This vector space has dimension ${n \choose k}$, and given a basis of $V$ as above, a basis of $\Lambda^k(V)$ is given by wedge products $e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_k}$ of $k$ distinct elements of a basis of $V$ in increasing order.

$\Lambda^k(V)$ has an inner product induced from the inner product on $V$ given by the Gram determinant $(v_1 \wedge \dots v_k) \cdot (w_1 \wedge \dots w_k) = \det (v_i \cdot w_j)$. It has the property that if $e_i$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ then the basis of wedge products as defined above is an orthonormal basis of $\Lambda^k(V)$.

This inner product induces a norm on $\Lambda^k(V)$, and the squared norm $\| v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k \|^2 = \det(v_i \cdot v_j)$ is the squared volume of the oriented parallelepiped determined by $v_1, \dots v_k$; equivalently, it is $k!^2$ times the squared volume of the $k$-simplex with vertices $0, v_1, \dots v_k$.

If we expand a wedge product $v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k = \sum c_{i_1, \dots i_k} e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_k}$ in terms of the orthonormal basis from above, then the coefficients $c_{i_1, \dots i_k}$ are the oriented volumes of the projection of the parallelepiped determined by $v_1, \dots v_k$ onto the coordinate hyperplane determined by $e_{i_1}, \dots e_{i_k}$.


These are all "well-known" although I wouldn't know where to direct you for proofs from scratch. The most interesting parts are the identification of all these formal calculations with concrete volumes. And with these the result is a simple calculation analogous to the calculation that proves the Pythagorean theorem in an inner product space: now we just have to write
$$v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k = \sum c_{i_1, \dots i_k} e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_k}$$
and then take the squared Euclidean norm of both sides, arriving at
$$\| v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k \|^2 = \sum c_{i_1, \dots i_k}^2.$$
These are the volumes of parallelepipeds but we can get the volumes of simplices by dividing both sides by $k!^2$. Of course this means the hard part of the proof is in the establishment of all the facts above, especially fact 4 (fact 3 is a corollary). Note that the statement you asked for is the case $k = n - 1$ but the argument works for any $k$.
